# Issue in my recursive algorithm for finding all shortest, unique paths

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, c++14, path-finding

I've been working on a recursive algorithm that is supposed to find all the shortest, unique possible paths to get from point A to point B in an n by m matrix. Currently I have it to the point where my algorithm can find all possible paths starting from a single direction. However when I get back to the first stack frame where the algorithm begins, I'm stuck with whatever directions have been taken in the previous actions taken in the first frame. I've determined that this is due to the fact that my movement function takes a reference to the current solution I'm working with. I think what needs to happen is that I need to further localize my parameters so that I in essence can start again from square one. I'm just jnot sure how to do that though because any time that I try to move away from passing references to my movement algorithm, the "solutions" come back as one letter.

Any tips on making the first stack frame more independent from my movement algorithm?

```
{void Robot::findTreasureHelper(Board whichBoard, int x, int y, std::string solution)

    ++callCount;

    if (x == TREASURE_X && y == TREASURE_Y)
    {
        ++numSolutions;
        return;
    }

    if (move(whichBoard, 'N', x, y, solution))
        findTreasureHelper(whichBoard, x, y, solution);
    if (move(whichBoard, 'E', x, y, solution))
        findTreasureHelper(whichBoard, x, y, solution);
    if (move(whichBoard, 'S', x, y, solution))
        findTreasureHelper(whichBoard, x, y, solution);
    if (move(whichBoard, 'W', x, y, solution))
        findTreasureHelper(whichBoard, x, y, solution);

    {bool Robot::move(Board& whichBoard, const char& whichDir, int& x, int& y, std::string& solution)

    bool didMove = false;

    int direction = 1;
    if (whichDir == 'S' || whichDir == 'E')
        direction = -1;
    int  *coordinate = &x;
    if (whichDir == 'N' || whichDir == 'S')
        coordinate = &y;

    //check bounds, consecutive movements, and whether robot has been here on this solution
    if (x == TREASURE_X && y == TREASURE_Y)
        *coordinate += direction;
    else if (*coordinate - direction >= 0 && *coordinate - direction < whichBoard.board.size() 
        && *coordinate - direction < whichBoard.board[y].size() && moveCount < CONSECUTIVE_MOVES)
    {
        *coordinate -= direction;
        //check blocks and previously been here
        if (whichBoard.board[y][x] == -1 || whichBoard.board[y][x] == currentSolutionIndex)
            *coordinate += direction;
        else if (x == TREASURE_X && y == TREASURE_Y)
        {
            switch (whichDir)
            {
            case 'N':
            case 'S':
                //check consecutive moves
                solution.back() == 'N' || solution.back() == 'S' ? ++moveCount : moveCount = 0;
                //add correct character to solution
                direction == 1 ? solution += 'N' : solution += 'S';
                break;
            case 'E':
            case 'W':
                //check consecutive moves
                solution.back() == 'E' || solution.back() == 'W' ? ++moveCount : moveCount = 0;
                //add correct character to solution
                direction == 1 ? solution += 'W' : solution += 'E';
                break;
            }
            //*coordinate += direction;
            this->solutions.push_back(solution);
            didMove = true;
        }
        else // complete the move randomly
        {
            switch (whichDir)
            {
            case 'N':
            case 'S':
                //check consecutive moves
                solution.back() == 'N' || solution.back() == 'S' ? ++moveCount : moveCount = 0;
                //add correct character to solution
                direction == 1 ? solution += 'N' : solution += 'S';
                break;
            case 'E':
            case 'W':
                //check consecutive moves
                solution.back() == 'E' || solution.back() == 'W' ? ++moveCount : moveCount = 0;
                //add correct character to solution
                direction == 1 ? solution += 'W' : solution += 'E';
                break;
            }
            didMove = true;
            whichBoard.board[y][x] = currentSolutionIndex;
        }

    }
    return didMove;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the shortest path, I would suggest you rather BFS than DFS so that you reach your solution faster. This can be done with the help of a queue. Start from your starting index, append the neighbours (in your case, your four neighbors N,S,E,W) into the queue.

Have a data structure to track all visited indices (preferably a set). So once you have these set up, repeatedly do the following -

1. Pop the element from the queue.
2. Check if that's your destination index, if it is you have found your shortest path.
3. If not, flag this index as visited and append it's neighbors to the queue.

Iterative solution - a clear bonus :)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm supposed to use recursion to solve this problem. In my understanding, BFS isn't really a recursive search type. Please correct me if I'm mistaken. Technically I'm an EE major and haven't had to delve too deep into computer science, so please forgive any ignorance I may have lol.